# Mail Merge Tool for Gmail With Ability to Change From Email Address

Tags: google-apps-script

I know there are some Mail Merge tools for Gmail. Are there any that allow me to use a registered "send from" address in gmail? When I set a different sending email within the two scripts here, it still sends from my default gmail account.

http://www.labnol.org/internet/personalized-mail-merge-in-gmail/20981/

Answer (score 0):

As a developer, you can code a script to use any of the aliases available in a Google account as the "from" address. Here is [a Google Apps Script documentation reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_gmailapp#getAliases) with an example (and copied below):

```
// The code below logs the aliases for this Gmail account and sends an email
// as the first one.
var aliases = GmailApp.getAliases();
Logger.log(aliases);
GmailApp.sendEmail(
    "recipient@example.com", "subject", "body", {from: aliases[0]});
```

Answer (score 0):

You might consider this App as a mail merge tool
http://www.thexs.ca/xsmerge
It's available in the Chrome web store (free)